# jar is faster in my machine but slower in other

Tags: java, performance, jar, performance-testing, executable-jar

I have a written a java program that uses multi-threads and prints the run-time when the processing is done.

I've created the jar file so I can test it on the university's server. Both the program in eclipse and the jar file runs perfectly on my machine (8 GB RAM and only 4 CPUs `Ubuntu`). But when I try to execute the jar on the server it's 2x slower! knowing that the virtual machine on the server has 8GB in RAM and 6 CPUs (`Debian`).

Why the jar file is slower on the virtual machine? I figured it's probably because of the JDK version on the Debian machine, so I updated JDK and JRE.

(Used Java version in `Debian`)

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-1~deb9u1-b11)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

(Java version on my "supposed-to-be-slower" `Ubuntu`)

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to say without being actually on that machine, there can be thousands of factors slowing it down. For example: Temprature of operating, operating clock freq, to the application logic..

Comment: Or other users executing other processes. Or CPU limitations for specific processes on the shared server.

Comment: I can understand what you are trying to say, but it's a dedicated server that only runs one virtual machine and I turn it off when I finish my task. Also, I have a very very noisy laptop ^^.

Comment: Time to learn to profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Java 7 there is almost no difference between OpenJDK and Oracle HotSpot, see the [Moving to OpenJDK as the official Java SE 7 Reference Implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310102422/https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/moving_to_openjdk_as_the) article.

If you want to compare execution on both Linux machines you can try profiling with [Flame Graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html):

> Flame graphs are a visualization of profiled software, allowing the most frequent code-paths to be identified quickly and accurately.

A good example how to use them is available [on Netflix tech blog](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/java-in-flames-e763b3d32166), especially the "The Problem with Profilers" section.